# Regex split with minimal length

Tags: regex

In C# I'm building an address parser. Suppose I have the address:

`Av. Rouxinol 101 - São Paulo - Brasil - CEP 04516-001 - Fone + 55 11 2151`

I wish to split the string into individual lines. Desired result is:

1. `Av. Rouxinol 101`
2. `São Paulo Brasil`
3. `CEP 04516-001`
4. `Fone + 55 11 2151`

Splitting by `-` will give me 5 lines; it will also split the CEP (Brazil postal code).

So, the logic I'd like to implement is that every part should at least be 6 characters long, so I guess I'd have to use lookbehind/forward?

So far I have:

```
(?<=.{6})-(?=.{6})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex `(?:^|(?<=\s-\s)).*?(?:(?=\s-\s[^-]{8,})|$)`

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string input = "Av. Rouxinol 101 - Sao Paulo - Brasil - CEP 04516-001 - Fone + 55 11 2151";
    Regex re = new Regex(@"(?:^|(?<=\s-\s)).*?(?:(?=\s-\s[^-]{8,})|$)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(input);
    foreach (Match m in matches) {
      Console.WriteLine(m);
    }
  }
}
```

*Test this code* [*here*](http://ideone.com/yy816).

Output:

```
Av. Rouxinol 101
Sao Paulo - Brasil
CEP 04516-001
Fone + 55 11 2151
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just split on `␣-␣` (spaces on either side of the dash). This will ensure that hyphens in the address itself aren't split apart.

Comment: Thanks Kolink! Though this would work in the example, the provided input is copy-n-pasted addresses from a multiple of souces, so it would be very possible that the provided input doesn't contain spaces. In an ideal world the pattern accounts for a minimum length of part.